# how can i share resources between users in wso2

Tags: resources, wso2

i have some resources at `wso2-management console`and i set permissions for roles and service providers to read these resources.

now, how can i share the resource_bank/database/registry_link or something like that between users.
or users how can reach to these resources except `wso2-management console` way?

i tried to send https://localhost:9443/carbon/resources/resource.jsp?region=region3&item=resource_browser_menu&path=/&loginStatus=true# address ,but it cant support post method .

thanks.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to share registry resources?

Comment: Exactly....i want another panel for my users that they login and i can share links of registry resources for them....

Comment: hi is this two separate nodes or a single pack? for a single pack  can you login to management console and access the path Home  > Resources  > Browse then select "permissions" select an existing user role and give the relevant permissions. Ideally all users with that role should be able to access the same resource.